# Git remote repository not having the same file structure as local

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I look at the remote repository's structure I see one of my Visual Studio projects in the wrong place. It is in the root folder. In the image below I am talking about the entry for CSS/Configuration/ALSTOM.CSS.Configuration.Menu. But when I look at the local file structure, I have a subfolder called CSS, and in that folder I have a subfolder called Configuration, etc. etc.
In the image, it should really just have a folder called CSS in the root. Like there is for the GCS folder.
In Visual Studio the folder structure is correct. And when I look at the local file system, it is also correct. I do not know how to fix this. I'm relatively new to Git and I was asked to fix this.

Edit: Is this a Bitbucket issue? Why it is not displaying the same folder structure?

[image: Folder in wrong place]

Comment: Here's a serious question: how do you know that the remote repository has a work-tree at all? If it does have a work-tree, how do you know what's in it? You are using a Web interface to browse *commits* stored in a repository over on Bitbucket but that does not mean that Bitbucket has any of those commits checked-out anywhere. The point of this question is not to say that you're wrong (or that you're right), but rather to get you to state what the *real problem* is: what is it that's not working?

Comment: Just omit the folder with *only one* subfolder recursively... like @torek says, what is it that's not working?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. I was asking why I see the structure differently when I look at it through the web browser on Bitbucket. My colleagues are asking me why the structure does not conform to how we actually have it in our Visual Studio solution or in our local file system. I had this situation with another folder, but that's because the folder was in the wrong location locally, so I moved it and pushed the changes, and that was fixed, and displayed properly in Bitbucket. The CSS folder is in the correct place locally. I want to see the same folder structure in Bitbucket. Is it Bitbucket?

Comment: According to bribroder's answer (which makes sense), that's just how Bitbucket show things. Instead of stopping at a directory (`CSS`), it checks to see if there's just one entity *in* that directory (`CSS/Configuration`), recursively until it either hits a point where there's more than one, or it has reached a plain file so that the recursion ends (`CSS/Configuration/ALSTOM.CSS.Configuration.Menu`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a design quirk of how the web UI shows you tree structure; if a directory has no files, only subdirectories, it is appended to its parent until you get to a directory with files in it. If the final directory has just one file in it, then the file is appended too. This has the plus of condensing a sparse tree structure so you can see more of it at once, and if you click that entry, both BitBucket and GitHub do you the favor of navigating directly to the single file or directory with files in it, so you didn't have to click through a bunch of pages. You will still see the full path in the breadcrumbs once you click through.